# Symfony2 Console and clipboard

Tags: symfony, console, clipboard

I am using Symfony2 Console as a stand alone component and I am looking for a way to copy some text on clipboard with a command. It must be for all Operating Systems.

For example:

```
php cli/console smth:copy
```

And when the command is run it must copy some text to user clipboard.

I've have google it and didn't found anything.
Is that possible an if is it how can i accomplish this task?

Comment: php itself cannot do this. It's better to just output the text and ask the user to copy and paste it themselves. Or if you can elaborate on your end goal we can help with that

Comment: You should also look at the individual utilities within each OS that copies text to clip, e.g. Linux - `xclip`, MacOS - `pbcopy` `pbpaste`, Windows (not all versions) - `clip.exe` more here: http://superuser.com/questions/97762/how-to-pipe-text-from-command-line-to-the-clipboard